# Angular server side rendering keeps going back to 502 errors

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, http-status-code-502

So I have been running my front end on the server for a few weeks now(angular Server Side rendering). I keep running into this issue where the front end goes down to a 502 error. I have to restart the server ever few hours to ensure that it is back up. The traffic is not crazy and everything seems to be fine(in my console logs- no errors etc) until the point it suddenly goes down. the moment I restart the ssr server, it works fine again. What could be the issue? what do I need to monitor? RAM? CPU? Something else?

Comment: Maybe the guys over at https://serverfault.com/ are better suited to help you in this matter. It sounds like a system configuration issue

Comment: alright thanks, will post there as well.